# Embed link in summary in Open graph

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I am new to Open graph. I ran into an issue where I am unable to add an `<a>` tag within an `og:description` tag. If I do so, the summary on my page appears like this:

```
Sample videos from from &nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com> Video1</a>
&nbsp;to&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">Video2</a>
```

Hence in the view source this appears as:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Sample videos from&amp;nbsp;&lt;
a  href=&quot;https://www.youtube.com&quot; 
target=&quot;_blank&quot;>video1&lt;/a>&amp;nbsp;to&amp;nbsp;&lt;a 
href=&quot;https://www.youtube.com&quot;
target=&quot;_blank&quot;>video2&lt;/a>" />
```

Is there a way I can embed a link inside og:description and make sure that the link appears without the tags in the summary while sharing on facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks are not allowed inside of a meta tag. Neither the HTML standard nor Facebook's OpenGraph standard supports what you have described.